# how to convert List<Model> to custom data in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there any easy way convert List to other model data?

this is my model:

```
class Account {
  String name;
  double balance;

  Account({required this.name, required this.balance});
}

class CategoryAccount {
  String type;
  List<Account> items;

  CategoryAccount({required this.type, required this.items});
}
```

this is sourceData:

```
List<Account> sourceData = [
  Account(name: 'cash', balance: 100),
  Account(name: 'cash', balance: 200),
  Account(name: 'bank', balance: 300),
  Account(name: 'creditor', balance: 400),
];
```

I want sourceData convert to finalData:

```
List<CategoryAccount> finalData = [
  CategoryAccount(
    type: 'cash',
    items: [
      Account(name: 'cash', balance: 100),
      Account(name: 'cash', balance: 200),
    ],
  ),
  CategoryAccount(
    type: 'bank',
    items: [
      Account(name: 'bank', balance: 300),
    ],
  ),
  CategoryAccount(
    type: 'creditor',
    items: [
      Account(name: 'creditor', balance: 300),
    ],
  ),
];
```

In Dart I saw the following method for a List : asMap(), but it's not doing what i expect: it use the list index as key. My questions:

Do you known anything in Dart libraries to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution without using a package:**

```
List<CategoryAccount> finalData = [];

for (var se in sourceData) {
  final index = finalData.indexWhere((fe) => fe.type == se.name);
  if (index >= 0) {
    finalData[index].items.add(se);
  } else {
    finalData.add(CategoryAccount(type: se.name, items: [se]));
  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- Line 3: Loop through each elements in the sourceData variable
- Line 4: Finding the index/position of the CategoryAccount object where the
  type matches with the element name
- Line 6: Adding the item to the
  existing CategoryAccount object if match found (step 4)
- Line 8: Else,
  create a new CategoryAccount and add the current element

---

**Using Set:**

```
final uniqueEles = sourceData.map((e) => e.name).toSet(); // unique list/set of names [ cash, bank, creditor ]

for (var se in uniqueEles) {
  finalData.add(CategoryAccount(
    type: se,
    items: sourceData.where((el) => el.name == se).toList(),
  ));
}
```

*a little credit to [Irfan Ganatra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74542715/5882307) for the hint. :)*

Comment: nice  ...short way of coding.....and look at my long long codes....but here I would like to know ..does it matter performance level...I mean ur code vs mine

Comment: The performance level doesn't matter, I only convert a small data, thanks again!

Comment: Thanks...got another input in knowledge box...its to toSet , I was creating UDF

Comment: Just a tip, it is considered very bad practice to use short name variables like that. Non-descriptive variables only make sense to the original coder, and probably won't make sense to them after a couple of months. Descriptive names are much more useful for everyone (including people learning here).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [collection](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) package like this:

```
var grouped = groupBy(
  sourceData,
  (Account element) => element.name,
);

var finalData = grouped.entries
    .map((e) => CategoryAccount(type: e.key, items: e.value))
    .toList();
for (var element in finalData) {
  print("type = ${element.type}");//cash, bank, creditor
}
```

Answer (score 2):

and here is kid logic way

```
List<String> fetch_available_name_from_sourcedata() {
  List<String> namelist = [];

  for (int x = 0; x < sourceData.length; x++) {
    if (!namelist.contains(sourceData[x].name))
      namelist.add(sourceData[x].name);
  }

  return namelist;
}

void main() {
  List<CategoryAccount> finaldata = [];
  List<String> namelist = fetch_available_name_from_sourcedata();

  for (int x = 0; x < namelist.length; x++) {
    finaldata.add(CategoryAccount(
        type: namelist[x],
        items: sourceData
            .where((element) => element.name == namelist[x])
            .toList()));
  }

//now you can see your final data as per your output...

  

}
```

Comment: You gave me an idea to simply your solution without the need of the ``fetch_available_name_from_sourcedata()`` method. Check my updated answer. Anyways, I upvoted for a nice try. :)

Comment: All other answers are better than mine answer..as it looks like kid way....I need to know..does it matter to performance  as I have taken many loops

Comment: yes it matters but don't worry, you'll learn :)

Comment: Thanks...and Thanks to StackOverflow it has your kind of experts that make possible to find better expert level codes...

Comment: you can use ``sourceData.map((e) => e.name).toSet();`` to get the unique list/set of the names. :) Check my edited answer :)